# What's wrong with the unchecked cast?

Tags: java

I'm reading J. Bloch's effective Java and now I'm at the arrays vs lists section. Here is an example of unchecked cast he provided:

```
interface Function<T> {
    T apply(T arg1, T arg2);
}

public class Main{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        Function<String> f = null;
        List<String> str = Arrays.asList("asd");
        //staff
        reduce(str, f, ""); //E's deduced to String. Where is type-unsafe?
    }
    static <E> E reduce(List<E> list, Function<E> f, E initVal) {
        E[] snapshot = (E[]) list.toArray(); // Unchecked cast
        E result = initVal;
        for (E e : snapshot)
            result = f.apply(result, e);
        return result;  
    }
}
```

He said that the method is not type-safe and we can easily get the `ClassCastException`. But I don't see how. Where's the type-unsafe, the type variable `E` will always be deduced to the appropriate type so we're no worried about class-cast-exeption.

Couldn't you give an example with throwing `ClassCastException`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no compile-time guarantee that `list.toArray()` will return the array of type `E[]`. Moreover it almost always returns an array of type `Object[]`. Thus depending on the later usage of this array you may have a `ClassCastException`. For example, consider the following code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    List<String> str = Collections.singletonList("asd");
    String[] array = test(str);
}

static <E> E[] test(List<E> list) {
    E[] snapshot = (E[]) list.toArray(); // Unchecked cast
    return snapshot;
}
```

Here you return this `E[]` array and the receiver expects that `String[]` array is returned. But actually it's `Object[]` array, thus you will get the `ClassCastException` in `main` method after the returned generic type is implicitly cast to the `String[]`.

In your code you can be sure that the array is used in safe way. But compiler is not smart enough to make this analysis, so it just warns you.

Answer (score 4):

The `list.toArray` idiom you employ here is not parametrized by an array of your `List`'s parametrized type, so it returns `Object[]`.

For instance, with your `List<String> str`, you can invoke: `String[] foo = str.toArray(new String[str.size()]);` without casting.

The problem here is that, due to Java generics' design, you can never initialize a `new E[]`, hence you have to cast to `(E[])`.

I cannot see this throwing a `ClassCastException` ever as is.

As others have mentioned, the "cosmetic" workaround is to add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before your `toArray` invocation, which will suppress the warning.

Comment: __I cannot see this throwing a ClassCastException ever as i__ neither can  I, but J. Bloch said that it could be easily changed to get one.

Answer (score 4):

> Object[]  toArray() Returns an array containing all of the elements in
>   this list in proper sequence (from first to last element).

We are casting this to E[] inferring generics so the cast is unchecked because jvm doesnt know what type E will be so the warning.

Say for example, E is String type(as in code by you). And we are trying to cast Object[] to String[], which can very well be Object[] to Integer[] for some other case. This validity cant be tested at compile/run time by jvm so the issue.

```
 public static void main( String[] args ){
    List<String> str = Arrays.asList("asf");
    //staff

    System.out.println(reduce(str, 2)); //E's deduced to String. Where is type-unsafe?
}
static <E, T> E reduce(List<E> list, T initVal) {
    Object snapshot = list.size(); // Unchecked cast   
    return (E) snapshot;
}
```

This will create class cast exception.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your cast, but with [Java Generics](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaArraysBreakTypeSafety):

```
static <E> E reduce(List<E> list, Function<E> f, E initVal) {
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"}) //nevermind
    E[] snapshot = (E[]) list.toArray(); //Unchecked cast
    E result = initVal;
    for (E e : snapshot)
        result = f.apply(result, e);
    return result;
}
```